# How to use more than one <instanceof> condition in <visibleWhen>?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, instanceof

There are two conditions for a popup menu to appear, I am using the `<instanceof..>` inside a `<visibleWhen>` tag in my plugin.xml? I have used the `<or>...<instance of>...</or>` but It doesn't seem to work. Below is the code

```
 <visibleWhen>
                 <with  variable="selection">
                            <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">

                         <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
                         <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                           value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
                           <or>
                            <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
                             <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                             value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
                           </or>
                  </iterate>
                  </with>
               </visibleWhen>
```

Any inputs would be really helpful !

Thanks,
Abbas

Comment: I've noticed you haven't cast any votes, even on answers you've accepted. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Alexey, I need at least 15 repuation points to do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `<or>` wrong (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions):

```
<with variable="selection">
    <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
        <or>
            <and>
                 <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
                 <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                       value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
            </and>
            <and>
                 <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
                 <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                       value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"/>
            </and>
       </or>
   </iterate>
</with>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. The usage of <or> wasn't right as you correctly pointed out. It's somewhat confusing, but that's how it works !